# Mouse click and keyboard not working in Mozilla Firefox version 49.0.1 and 50.0

Tags: c#, firefox

When I use Google Chrome, my Web applications work fine.

When I open them in Mozilla Firefox, mouse clicks and keyboard strokes do not properly work.

I have also tried it on Mozilla safe mode and have refreshed Mozilla's settings.

I have even tried reinstalling Mozilla Firefox, but the problem remains.

Comment: Please, can you paste the source code who handles the click event?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.